# Protractor - jasmine TypeError: cannot read property 'result' of undefined

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Recently i encounter an issue below, whenever i try to execute protractor tests remotely.

I receive an error message upon execution:

```
 npm run e2e:remote

> hogs@0.1.22 e2e:remote /home/user/projects/project
> ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor e2e/protractor.remote.conf.js

[09:34:07] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[09:34:07] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
Jasmine started
```

/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:5120
        return children && children[0].result.status;
                                       ^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
    at isAfterAll (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:5120:36)
    at Suite.onException (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:5083:8)
    at Suite.onException (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:5095:27)
    at QueueRunner.onException (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:5191:28)
    at onException (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4310:14)
    at handleError (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:4243:11)
    at process.onerror (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2371:17)
    at process.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at process.emit (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:439:21)
    at process.emit (/home/user/projects/project/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:485:21)
```

Due to the above, i am unable to run tests at all at remote.

my protractor.conf.js:

```
    require('dotenv').config();

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

/**
 * @type { import("protractor").Config }
 */
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: process.env.SELENIUM_SERVER_ADDRESS || `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`,
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: ['./src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'],
  // directConnect: true,
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      shardTestFiles: false,
      maxInstances: 2,
    },
    //{
    // browserName: 'firefox',
    //},
  ],
  maxSessions: -1,
  baseUrl: process.env.REMOTE_URL || "",
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {},
  },
  onPrepare() {
    process.env.USER_EMAIL = process.env.USER_EMAIL || '';
    process.env.USER_PASSWORD = process.env.USER_PASSWORD || '';

    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json',
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  },
};
```

Tests run smoothly when i uncomment the directconnect, though in our project we are supposed to run tests through selenium grid, so it is vital that remote runs without it.

Jasmine version is 3.5.0,
Protractor is ver 5.4.3.